# Definite article when we talk about "something" that is a part of "any, arbitarary" thing

Tags: articles, definite-article

Here is a sentence from my instruction for LibreOffice Writer users:

> To change the measurement unit of table columns to a percentage, [you need to...]

My question is whether to put "the" before "table columns".

On the one hand, it seems to me that we mean specific columns. This is because the same sentence can be written as:

> To change the measurement unit of ***the*** columns of ***a*** table to a percentage, [you need to...]

Here it becomes clear that although the table is "any", its columns are "specific". Right?

But on the other hand,

> To change the measurement unit of the table columns to a percentage, [you need to...]

simply doesn't sound correct to me, for some reason.

Comment: I'd say the LibreOffice Writer text (which *doesn't* attach an article to the noun phrase "table columns") is the "better" choice, but that needn't imply it's actually *incorrect* to include one.  It's really a stylistic choice. Note that just because switching from the noun adjunct "table columns" to preposition-based "columns of a table" makes it more *likely* the article will be included, it's still not *required* even there. Also note that changing from noun adjunct to preposition makes no difference to the meaning, which strongly implies that *columns are "specific"* is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks, FumbleFingers.

Comment: Note that the relevant utterance could avoid using *any* articles: *To change table column measurement units to percentages...* A native Anglophone *speaking* to other native Anglophones might well choose that format, without needing to worry about whether it would be easily understood. But I (and presumably the LibreOffice copywriter) can see that non-native Anglophones might find that a little harder to parse, so it's better to choose phrasing that you think won't confuse your target audience / readership.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or even "To set table column widths in percentages", I suppose. :-)

Comment: You could apply for a job writing LibreOffice technical manuals! :)